# Class.forName equivalent for creating ParameterizedType's from String

Tags: java, generics

Calling `java.lang.reflect.Type.toString()` provides very nice representation of generic types:

```
@Test
public void typeToStringWithTypeToken() {
    assertEquals("java.util.List<java.lang.String>", new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType().toString());
}
```

What I need is the reverse of `Type.toString()` method, i.e. a method that can create `Type`s from given string representation:

```
public static Type parseTypeString(String typeString) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (typeString.indexOf('<') == -1) {
        return Class.forName(typeString);
    }
    // ??? how to implement rest
    throw new IllegalStateException("not implemented");
}
```

Which can pass following tests with specialized types:

```
@Test
public void justSimpleClassName() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(Integer.class, parseTypeString("java.lang.Integer"));
}

@Test
public void listOfInteger() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {}.getType(), parseTypeString("java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>"));
}

@Test
public void complexType() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(new TypeToken<Map<List<Integer>, Set<String>>>() {}.getType(), parseTypeString("java.util.Map<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>"));
}
```

I couldn't find a library or a SO question that addresses this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... You can do it by yourself using for example [antlr4](http://www.antlr.org/) using following grammar

```
type returns[ClassBuilder value]
    : cls=CLASS          { $value = ClassBuilder.parse($cls.text); }
    | cls=CLASS          { $value = ClassBuilder.parse($cls.text); }
      LT head=type       { $value.add($head.value); }
        (COMMA tail=type { $value.add($tail.value); })* GT
    ;

GT  : '>'
    ;

LT  : '<'
    ;

COMMA
    : ','
    ;

CLASS
    : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'$'|'.'|'_')*
    ;
```

Where `ClassBuilder` looks like

```
public class ClassBuilder {
    private final Class<?> clazz;
    private final List<ClassBuilder> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

    public ClassBuilder(final Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public static ClassBuilder parse(String clazz) {
        try {
            return new ClassBuilder(Class.forName(clazz));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // do better handling here
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public void add(ClassBuilder builder) {
        parameters.add(builder);
    }

    public Type build() {
        // class is not parametrized
        if (parameters.isEmpty()) {
            return clazz;
        }

        return ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(
                clazz,
                parameters.stream()
                          .map(ClassBuilder::build)
                          .toArray(Type[]::new),
                null);
    }
}
```

And then finally parse string

```
CharStream stream = 
    new ANTLRInputStream(
        "java.util.Map<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>"
    );

TokenStream tokenStream = 
    new CommonTokenStream(new ParametrizedTypeLexer(stream));
ParametrizedTypeParser parser = 
    new ParametrizedTypeParser(tokenStream);

assertEquals(
        new TypeToken<Map<List<Integer>, Set<String>>>() {}.getType(),
        parser.type().value.build()
);
```

You can see working example [here](https://github.com/KetothXupack/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/q39401083).

**NOTE**

`CLASS` lexer rule may be a bit inaccurate. Also this parser only applies to non-primitive classes and parametrized types, but you of course extend it to support wildcard types as well.

Comment: That's a great answer! I'll test it and provide further feedback. People might need to notice the tricky part of the implementation, using `ParameterizedTypeImpl` from **private** API ([ParameterizedTypeImpl.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/reflect/generics/reflectiveObjects/ParameterizedTypeImpl.java)). I guess Java folks try to discourage us mere mortals performing black magic by not providing public `ParameterizedType` implementation.

Comment: @b10y afaik there is ParameterizedType implementations in guava but there is no problem to implement it by hands

Answer (score 1):

The output of `java.lang.reflect.Type.toString()` is implementation specific.
The behaviour you are seeing is part of Gson's [`ParameterizedTypeImpl`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ee8d6be59ff6f2466d65be746b96ccf07ddb9ddf/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/%24Gson%24Types.java#L437)
Due to type erasure, classes in Java don’t have type parameters at runtime.
The `Type` from gson doesn’t represent an actual loaded `Class`.

See [Get Type of ParameterizedType from generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179759/get-type-of-parameterizedtype-from-generic) for related information.